# SQL Server Count Sequential Breakpoints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 table that stores whether a customer is Active for a particular week. I want to output a results that shows me how many weeks in a row a customer was active along with start week and end week. I have the below code but that only gives me total number of weeks a customer was active. Is it possible to break the counts in sequence? Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT
    ActiveYN
    ,MIN(StartWeek)
    ,MAX(StartWeek)
    ,COUNT(*)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ActiveYN
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a gaps-and-islands problem.  One solution uses a difference of row numbers:

```
select customer, activeyn,
       min(startweek), max(startweek)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by customer order by startweek) -
              row_number() over (partition by customer, activeyn order by startweek)
             ) as grp
      from tablea t
     ) t
group by customer, activeyn, grp;
```

The calculation looks a bit like a magical incantation.  But, if you run the subquery and look at the results for each `row_number()` calculation, you'll understand why the difference defines the groups you are looking for.